# Simulate movement of game object as if server handles requests with lag

Tags: c#, algorithm, latency

Question: Can anybody give me an idea about how I can write an custom algorithm, to move an object from point A to point B with latency?

I am currently using a pretty simple algorithm:

1. While(input is held) Add a point to current existing List of points
2. Check if the list exceeds the maximum offset (a given number of points) -> 
   a.Move the object over the 0 index point. b.Delete the 0 index point.
3. Loop back to 1.

But this algorithm does not give me desired results.I am looking maybe for some kind of math expression to do that lag simulation, but I am not really sure can it be produced with math anyway so I headed first here to ask the question.

Comment: What do you mean "movement with lag"? "Lag" in relation to what?

Comment: i used the term "movement with lag" in order to illustrate it more simply, but now I see it can confuse somebody.Let me give it another shot: 1) In a network, latency, a synonym for delay, is an expression of how much time it takes for a packet of data to get from one designated point to another....I am trying to achieve it with an object

Comment: To move an object from point A to point B with latency l

Comment: I'm still not sure how it is different from just moving an object at constant speed of (distance AB/time to reach B)...

Comment: The difference is it will move with constant speed, but with some sort of delay on actions in time.

Comment: One more time - "delay" compared to what? You can't have "sort of delay" when you don't know when it would happen without delay...

Comment: Maybe to illustrate it better just imagine you are playing some online  game and suddenly the server get's lagged.If you clicked somewhere on the map in the current lag time the character moves to the old clicked position not the new one.Until the lag goes off.

Comment: That's easy - just delay information where to go (like mark "go to new destination after CurrentTime + 5" instead of "CurrentTime") and handle that event when time comes.

Comment: Thanks I guess I overlooked some things.Never though of that solution...

Comment: I've updated title to what I think your goal is, feel free to edit (reverting is an option, but original title was very confusing).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some sort of user input and way to process events.

One approach is to explicitly delay user input events (or any other events) to some later time. I.e. when user clicks to send game object to new position instead of setting it as new immediate target you can put action into list of future events "Move to point B, starting CurrentTime + Delay".

As result your code will not be aware of the request to change destination and continue moving object to its previous target till "Delay" time passed.